# PHP Using cURL and GET request in URL

Tags: php, url, curl, get

I am using cURL instead of file_get_contents, which is working fine on the URL until I used a GET request variable in place of the city on the URL below.

Using cURL on the following: (Works)

`$url = 'http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/London/forecasts/latest';`

This works fine, however when substituting 'London' with a variable `$city`:

```
URL: example.com/weather.php?city=London

$city = $_GET['city'];
$city = ucwords($city); 
$city = str_replace(" ", "", $city);

$url = 'http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/".$city."/forecasts/latest';
```

I get an error: `The page you are looking for doesn't exist (404)`

**What am I doing wrong in my cURL function? This seems to work perfectly with `file_get_contents`, is there something I am missing?**

**cURL function**

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$contents = curl_get_contents($url);
echo $contents;
```

Comment: Your quotes are mismatched on `$url`. You're opening with single quotes then attempting to close half way through with a double quote.

Comment: try single quotes around city in $url

Comment: Perfect, can someone put it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace double quotes with single quotes in url,

```
$url = 'http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'.$city.'/forecasts/latest';
```