# strpos() error using Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: javascript, php

Simple HTML DOM Parser (1 min, 39s)

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $i = 0;
    $times_to_run = 100;
    set_time_limit(0);

    while ($i++ < $times_to_run) {
        // Find target image
        $url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/".$i;
        $html = file_get_html($url);
        $element = $html->find('img.game_header_image_full');

        if($i == $times_to_run) {
            echo "Success!";
        }

        foreach($element as $key => $value){
        // Check if image was found
            if (strpos($value,'img') == false) {
                // Do nothing, repeat loop with $i++;

            } else {
                // Add (don't overwrite) to file steam.txt
                file_put_contents('steam.txt', $url.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

vs. the cURL alternative.. (34s)

```
<?php

    $i = 0;
    $times_to_run = 100;
    set_time_limit(0);

    while ($i++ < $times_to_run) {

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/'.$i);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);

        $url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/".$i;

        $reg = "/<\\s*img\\s+[^>]*class=['\"][^'\"]*game_header_image_full[^'\"]*['\"]/i";

        if(preg_match($reg, $content)) {
            file_put_contents('steam.txt', $url.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
        }

    }

?>
```

For some reason, the first one managed to catch 9 URL's, whilst the 2nd one (cURL) only caught 8 URL's with preg_match. Does it timeout automatically or something, or is the `preg_match` just not as well aimed as the `$html->find('img.game_header_image_full')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would stand to reason that you would simply be interested in a situation where `$element`(s) is not empty:

```
$found = $html->find('img.game_header_image_full');
if(!empty($found)) {
    file_put_contents('steam.txt', $url.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
}
```

This would also avoid the situation where `$html->find()` returns more than one result (which could happen, considering that the selector is class based, and not based on an ID.

Further, you may consider the performance implications of using an HTML parser.  It would be much more performant to use `Curl` to retrieve data, and a regular expression to find your element (as you are only looking for the class-name, and the HTML is in a predictable format):

```
$reg = "/<\\s*img\\s+[^>]*class=['\"][^'\"]*game_header_image_full[^'\"]*['\"]/i";
if(preg_match($reg, $raw_source)) {
    file_put_contents('steam.txt', $url.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
}
```

May be much more performant.  The regular expression essentially says:

```
Starts with an open tag.
Zero or more whitespace.
Tag is `img`
Zero or more whitespace.
Any character that is not an end-tag.
Class declaration.
The class declaration contains `game_header_image_full`.
```

Working here: https://regex101.com/r/fQ8lJ1/1

Further: if you use Multi Curl, [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34399853/1301994), you will see speed like you can't even imagine right now.

And one last thing: If you are doing this from the comand-line, consider simple `echo` statements, instead of appends.  This will allow you to test, and you can append to a file at run-time when you are ready to go, like so:

```
$ php file_to_execute.php >> steam.txt
```

Comment: The first code I understood. The rest is kind of a blur to me, can't put it into any real context hah. I'm sure cURL is great, I might move over to it as soon as I've gotten the hang of this. Sorry to leave this lame response to such an elaborate explaination, I thank you for it though.

Comment: NP, if the first bit helps, feel free to continue on and re-visit this in the future.  It may make a good exercise at a later date.  Multi Curl essentially allows all requests to resolve concurrently, meaning that you will complete all 100 iterations in about the same amount of time as 1 request and 100 searches (super fast, comparatively).

Comment: Yeah. This is working right now, but it is kinda slow. It only needs to be done once though, then I'll try and make something out of the results. This is a super lame question I know, but could you help me formulate a good search query for something similar to what I'm doing? I'm trying, but I'm not using the right keywords it seems, everything I get looks really 'advanced', and can't really be applied to my case.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start. How do I select a particular object in cURL (what's the function called that is similar to `$html->find('img.game_header_image_full');`), etc. [Found this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454540/php-using-curl-and-get-request-in-url), but I can't see some sort of element selector.

Comment: Hmm, or do I combine it with Simple HTML DOM? I'll figure it out, thanks for all help though. I'm a COMPLETE newb, as I said.. :D

Comment: In cURL you don't, hence the `preg_match`

Comment: I managed to build a working cURL thing with preg_match (thanks btw). It was much faster, problem is that it only got 8 results, and my regular Simple HTML DOM Parser got 9 results. The last one (/app/100) was only caught by Simple HTML DOM Parser, but not the cURL alternative (same conditions, `$i=0 $i++ > $i=100`). Any clue why? I'll edit my post with the two alternatives..

Comment: Regex problem, right. Thank you once again for your help Mike. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

for question N 1

try a loop over the array and then inside the loop use the strpos..
(adatpt to you need the strpos evalutation

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$i = 0;
$times_to_run = 100;

while ($i++ < $times_to_run) {
    // Find target image
    $url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/".$i;
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $element = $html->find('img.game_header_image_full');

    forarch($elemnt as $key => $value){
         // Check if image was found
         if (strpos($value,'img') == false) {
             // Do nothing, repeat loop with $i++;

         } else {
            // Add (don't overwrite) to file steam.txt
        file_put_contents('steam.txt', $url.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
       }
    }
}
?>
```